Unable to update deployed features for bundle
I'm facing an issue in Nexus (version 3.x) where nothing I changed. My Nexus service is running, but showing lots of error related to different bundles like
1.
ERROR [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.apache.karaf.deployer.features.FeatureDeploymentListener - Unable to update deployed features for bundle: org.apache.felix.framework - 6.0.5
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.karaf.deployer.features.FeatureDeploymentListener.bundleChanged(FeatureDeploymentListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.karaf.deployer.features.FeatureDeploymentListener.init(FeatureDeploymentListener.java:90)
        at org.apache.karaf.deployer.features.osgi.Activator$DeploymentFinishedListener.deploymentEvent(Activator.java:86)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.registerListener(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:296)




ERROR [FelixDispatchQueue]  *SYSTEM org.apache.karaf.deployer.features.FeatureDeploymentListener - Unable to u
pdate deployed features for bundle: org.apache.karaf.log.core - 4.3.6
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.karaf.deployer.features.FeatureDeploymentListener.bundleChanged(FeatureDeploymentListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:915)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:1147)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.access$000(EventDispatcher.java:54)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher$1.run(EventDispatcher.java:102)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I tried clearing the cache of Nexus, restarting the service, but tjos did not work. I expect Nexus in running status and error free, so I can see its dashboard and work.

I tried to install version 3.38.1 on a new VM, but I encountered the same NullPointerException issue

Any update on this? Seem to be facing the same issue. No idea why this suddenly pops up.

Yes its resolved by changing nexus version. that same version setup on new server giving same errors.

Resolved. I tried to set up the same version(3.38) on another server and encountered the same issues. So, I installed version 3.40, and it worked. After that, I simply performed the migration, and my Nexus is up and running.
